# Style succes function ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Heeeeelp! :)

I have a problem with my code. I want to make a dropdown filter using ajax, php & json. The first dropdown menu (build year for car) is loaded true php. In the second dropdown menu you have to choose the brand of the car. This is done true ajax request and php. Everything works, but ajax does not style the  element. Anyone knows how i can fix this?

AJAX code

```
function showBrand(sel) {
var selectedYear = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
$("#output1").html( "" );
$("#output2").html( "" );
if (selectedYear.length > 0 ) { 

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fetch_state.php",
        data: "selectedYear="+selectedYear,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () { 
            $('#output1').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
        },
        success: function(html) {    
            $("#output1").html( html );
            $("#output1").addClass( "section colm colm6");
        }
    });
}
```

}

PHP code

```
    require("configure.php");
$car_brand = ($_REQUEST["selectedYear"] <> "") ? trim( addslashes($_REQUEST["selectedYear"])) : "";
if ($car_brand <> "" ) { 
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT make FROM VehicleModelYear WHERE year = ".$car_brand ." ORDER BY make desc";
$count = mysql_num_rows( mysql_query($sql) );
if ($count > 0 ) {
$query = mysql_query($sql);

?>

<div class="section colm colm6">
<label for="carBrand" class="field-label">(*) Merk</label>
<select name="brand" onchange="showCity(this);">
    <option value="">Selecteer merk</option>
    <?php while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rs["make"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["make"]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?> 
</select>
<i class="arrow double"></i>
</label>
</div>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

HTML code // Here must be the second dropdown, loaded true ajax..

```
            <div id="output1">
                        </div><!-- end section -->
```

Comment: what is `#ouput1`? When you provide script that doesn't match the html you provide, how can we tell what the problem might be?

Comment: Sorry, #output1 is the id of a div element where the output has to come. I will edit my post! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `<element id="output1"/>` exists your jQuery looks fine.

Check your browser net tab (f12) to see if it was able to locate `loader.gif`

**Edit**

when I said check that `<element>` exists, i didn't mean literally `element` I meant in general like a div etc, since you're original post contained no reference to `output1`

this is obviously some issue with `jQuery ui` or `smartform`

Try changing:

```
<element id="output1" class="section colm colm6">
  <div class="section colm colm6">
    <label class="field-label" for="carBrand">(*) Merk</label>
       <select onchange="showCity(this);" name="brand">
         <option value="">Selecteer merk</option>
     <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
          ....

         </select>
     <i class="arrow double"></i>
  </div>
</element>
```

To:

```
  <div id="output1" class="section colm colm6">
    <label class="field-label" for="carBrand">(*) Merk</label>
       <select onchange="showCity(this);" name="brand">
         <option value="">Selecteer merk</option>
     <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
          ....

         </select>
     <i class="arrow double"></i>
  </div>
```

Whatever it is that you're using to style the form, jQuery ui or smartform, I couldn't figure it out must have some method to apply styles post pageload. you'll need to call that method in your ajax success method.

Comment: Yes, the loader.gif works if i make my first selection (filter year to models)

Comment: ok, then you may need to explain what "ajax does not style the element" means

Comment: You can see it live, here is the link :) http://debotechnics.be/project/form/ Select something in the top box, the second dropdown is loaded right!

Comment: check your browser console `NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://debotechnics.be/project/form/fetch_city.php` try adding the absolute path in the ajax url

Comment: I know, could that be the problem? It's exactly the same file as the php file i've provided on top. This file is for the third dropdown selection..

Comment: yup that's the problem, if the browser cannot load `fetch_city.php` it can't load the ajax content

Comment: I've removed the script for fetch_city. The second dropdown is still not styled. I want the same style dropdown as the first one. Can you check again please? I really have no clue where the problem may be located!

Comment: And the ajax script is working fine, with the fetch_city. I can make selections on my test platform...

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem:

your `<#output/>` looks like this:

```
<div id="output1" class="section colm colm6">
    <div class="section colm colm6">
        <label for="carBrand" class="field-label">(*) Merk</label>
        <select name="brand" onchange="showCity(this);">
            <option value="">Selecteer merk</option>
            <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
            ...
        </select>
        <i class="arrow double"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

It should look like this:

```
<div id="output1">
    <div class="section colm colm6">
        <label for="carBrand" class="field-label">(*) Merk</label>
---->   <label class="field select state-succes">    <---------------you miss this label
            <select name="brand" onchange="showCity(this);">
                <option value="">Selecteer merk</option>
                <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
                ...
            </select>
            <i class="arrow double"></i>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

- You're missing the encapsulating `<label class="field select state-succes">` that is present in your first dropmenu.

---

Also, this `$("#output1").addClass( "section colm colm6");` adds the class to `#output`, but it already contains an extra `div` with that same class. It messes up the alignment of the dropdown in the form.
Either remove that extra `div` that has the same class, or don't add the class to `#output`.